# How to prove there exist a cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, where degree of each vertex is at least $d$ and $d ≥ 2$, there must be
a cycle of length at least $d + 1$ in $G$.

Given that $d\geq2$ that proves that no of edges is greater than number on nodes that means there exist surely an graph.

but how to prove there exist cycle of  length atleast   d+1.

any Hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the longest path $P$ in $G$. Let $v$ be an endpoint of the path. It follows that all neighbors of $v$ must be on $P$, for otherwise we can extend $P$ contradicting maximality. There exists at least $d$ neighbors of $v$ on $P$. Let $u$ be the neighbor of $v$ furthest away from $u$ on $P$. Then $vPuv$ is a cycle of length at least $d+1$.

By the way, you cannot conclude that $|E| > |V|$ from the assumption $d\ge 2$ (nor is the assumption necessary). Consider any cycle for example.

**Edit**: We are not saying that our path $P$ is a cycle, but rather that it contains a cycle. For definiteness, let us say 
$$P=(v_0,\ v_1,\ v_2,\ \cdots,\ v_k)$$ 
Then we know that $k\ge d$ and that $v_0$ has all its neighbors in $P$. Say the neighbors are 
$$N(v_0) = \{v_{i_1},\ \cdots,\ v_{i_\ell}\}$$ 
where $\ell = \deg(v_0)$. Therefore we have the cycle 
$$C=(v_0,\ v_1,\ \cdots,\ v_{i_\ell}, v_0)$$ 
We know that 
$$i_\ell \ge \ell=\deg(v_0) \ge d$$ 
so $C$ has length at least $d+1$

Comment: Note: you are assuming the graph is finite (and the assumption is neccessary). For infinite graphs, a longest path may not exist (nor a cycle)

Comment: I did not understand why can't we extent P. There may be a case (P+1) is connected to P but it cannot reach the 1 node .

Comment: @TLE $P$ is already assumed to be the _longest_ path. If we can extend it, then it would become even _longer_. That's a problem.

Comment: @EuYu My question is how can we say all neighbours  of P are in cycle it may be the case p has one neighbour outside the circle but we cannot include it in our max length cycle.

Comment: @TLE Let's say $v$ is an endpoint of our path $P$. Say that $u$ is a neighbor of $v$ which is _not_ on $P$. Then $P\cup \{u\}$ is a longer path than $P$. I'm still not too sure where exactly you're confused.

Comment: @EuYu We are saying our path P is cycle??right.Than How can we say $P U \{ u \}$ is cycle.

Comment: @TLE Please see the edit. Is the answer more clear now?